# How does the app life cycle works in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation, redux-saga

I got a React-Native app with react-navigation. We decided to use one top-level [navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html) and use actions to navigate.

This all works like a charm, except when the app goes to the background and back to the foreground. If the OS didn't terminate the app (when you keep it in the background for too long or do other memory-intensive stuff), all is ok, but when the OS decided to kill it, the app reloads when being opened. This is where strange things are happening: A lot of the code is being re-executed (app.js is being re-executed again for example), but a lot of code is not (static js-classes for example).

So my question is: how does React-Native determine what is being restarted and what not, is it just App.js and the components? And what happens with middleware frameworks like redux, redux-saga, etc...?

To provide a concrete example:

App.js:

```
Navigator = createStackNavigator(routes, {headerMode: 'screen', initialRouteName: 'Launch'});

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <Navigator ref={navigatorRef => {NavigationService.setNavigator(navigatorRef)}}/>
        </View>
     </Provider>
   )
  }
}
```

NavigationService.js (static class, all functions are called from saga's through actions:

```
let _navigator;

function setNavigator(navigatorRef) {
  _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

//All navigate functions
```

The above code works like a charm until restart, then a new navigator is attached to here, but the old one does still exists and gives tons of errors. I tried to not replace the navigator, which prevents the errors, but through App.render() the new navigator is there anyway, and you're stuck on the initial screen.

I would like to have some more insides in how React-Native handles this app reload, but if you have a solution for this specific problem, please share!

Answer (score 0):

You can add lifecycle function like componentDidMount in your app.js.I don't know which js-classs is not reexecuted.Can you show some example code?